# How to get the text from array of textviews then store the getted text in a string array

Tags: android, textview

Hi am developing an android application i have a problem like i have 10 textviews i need to get the each and every textview text and store that text in a string array..

Please help me.. thanks in advance..

Comment: textviews[0].getText().toString();

Comment: actually i called all this textviews in my program like this Integer[] Textview = {
   R.id.score_text_01,
   R.id.score_text_02,
   R.id.score_text_03,
   R.id.score_text_04,
   R.id.score_text_05,
   R.id.score_text_06,
   R.id.score_text_07,
   R.id.score_text_08,
   R.id.score_text_09,
   R.id.score_text_10
                              
 };

Comment: when am trying to creat an array with textview like final Textview[] text={}  its throws error in R.java file thats why i created an integer aray..

Comment: can you please explain when do you do findViewById ?

Comment: something like this: private TextView displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DisplayTextView);, then to retrieve text displayTextView.gettext();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s = textView.getText().toString();
```

Comment: This is ok for now ab able to assign it to string..and one more thing i need to verify that string(this i have converted it into integer array) and place the highest number on first textview how can i do that ...thanks in advance...

Comment: This may help you.    String s[] = {"2","5","10"};
        Arrays.sort(s);
        System.out.println(s[0]);